# Comparing two CGRects

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, comparison, cgrect

I needed to check wether the frame of my view is equal to a given CGRect. I tried doing that like this:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20);
if (self.view.frame == rect)
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

However, I got an error saying `Invalid operands to binary expression('CGRect' (aka 'struct CGRect') and 'CGRect')`. Why can't I simply compare two `CGRect`s?

Answer (score 257, accepted):

Use this:

```
if (CGRectEqualToRect(self.view.frame, rect)) {
     // do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 40):

See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1456516-cgrectequaltorect?language=objc) for CGRectEqualToRect().

```
bool CGRectEqualToRect ( CGRect rect1, CGRect rect2 );
```

Answer (score 6):

In the Swift 3 it would be:

```
frame1.equalTo(frame2)
```

Comment: in fact, `equalTo(_:)` is now [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1456516-equalto) so `==` is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift simply using the `==` or `!=` operators works for me:

```
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)

    if rect != CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 21) {
        print("not equal")
    }

    if rect == CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20) {
        print("equal")
    }
```

debug console prints:

```
not equal
equal
```